# Вопрос по сервисам

Tags: c#, сервисы

Добрый день.

Объясните мне пожалуйста такой вопрос:

Мне ранее приходилось работать с серисами - я формировал POST запрос и отправлял по указанного УРЛ. Сейчас у меня есть свой веб-сервис, я знаю его УРЛ и порт, и вот скажите - как сделать так,  чтобы можно было формировать POST-запрос так, как в примере ниже :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(is_card_URL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PARAMETERS);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream2);

string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
stream2.Close();
```

В моем сервисе есть тестовый метод "Test" с параметрами "param1","param2". Есть ли возможность  (и есть ли смысл - ведь можно работать через прокси-класс) сделать так ,чтобы мой сервис вызывался на подобии примера выше?

Может я что-то не дописал или непонятно написал, выскажите, я исправлю.

Спасибо.

Comment: Да, поменяйте значение `is_card_URL` на свой url - будет вызыватся точно так-же как в вашем примере(правда это ужасно криво сделанный пример, но если именно так, тогда ок :) ). В чем вопрос то?

Comment: Вопросы был в том, как вызвать метод моего сервиса "Test" с параметрами так, как в примере сказано. Я попробую вашу идею, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простенький прокси для вашего веб-сервиса на базе стандартного HttpClient:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// Простенький класс, иллюстрирующий потребление RESTfull-сервиса
/// </summary>
public class ServiceProxy : HttpClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Конструктор прокси-класса
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="endpoint">Url вашего сервиса</param>
    public ServiceProxy(Uri endpoint)
    {
        this.BaseAddress = endpoint;
    }

    public ServiceProxy() : this(new Uri("http://example.com/MyService/"))
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вызывает метод "Test"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param1">Параметр 1</param>
    /// <param name="param2">Параметр 2</param>
    /// <returns>Строка возвращенная сервисом</returns>
    public async Task<string> TestAsync(string param1, string param2)
    {
        var args = new Dictionary<string,string>()
        {
            { "param1", param1 },
            { "param2", param2 }
        };
        var response = await this.PostAsync("Test", new FormUrlEncodedContent(args));

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public string Test(string param1, string param2)
    {
        return this.TestAsync(param1, param2).Result;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я до этого времени думал, это 2 совсем разные, не пересекающиеся реализации ( имею в виду POST и прокси класс). Спасибо.

Comment: @LeonardBertone, вы же действительно имели ввиду [Прокси-классы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29), а не классы для работы с прокси-серверами(просто посмотрел на ваши предыдущие вопросы здесь)?

Comment: именно Прокси-класс (Sergey Rufanov , не смог обратиться к вам через @). спасибо